# How to find sql server instance?

Tags: windows, sql-server

I have sql server 2000 and 2005  installed on my machine.

Now instances were installed as Machine04 [2000] and other Machine04\SomeInstance [2005] (this some instance i don't remember now) So is there any way i can find available instances.

Because of this now i am only able to connect to sql 2000 only and other way is to reinstall 2005 which is really not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Services.msc, it will be listed there as "SQL Server (Instance Name)"

Comment: Can we change the name of sql server instance which is installed?

Comment: Yes, you can.  See here:  http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/tools/archive/2007/12/14/rename-a-sql-server-instance-a-little-catch.aspx